# Load csproj The attribute "ExcludeAssets" in element <PackageReference> is unrecognized

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj, packagereference

Using Microsoft.Build component to load a csproj using method ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.LoadProject. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectcollection.loadproject?view=msbuild-16-netcore#Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_ProjectCollection_LoadProject_System_String_).

Loading a csproj with PackageReference and ExcludeAsset attribute in one of the references, example:

```
 <PackageReference Include="SomePackage" ExcludeAssets="Compile">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
  </PackageReference>
```

The following exception is thrown:

**The attribute "ExcludeAssets" in element  is unrecognized.**

Already tried different ToolVersions (2.0 | 4.0 |12.0), and both of the projects are compiled in .net472

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I believe that is only supported for dotnet core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj

Comment: the csproj is valid and compiles properly. (old csproj format with PackageReferences)
so, on my understanding using ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.LoadProject to load it should not throw any kind of exception
thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that is related to @AluanHaddad response. The project that is calling ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.LoadProject. if it uses the new SDK style, is able to load an older csproj with packagereferences and ExcludeAssets attribute.